# Stack buttons horizontally with their text in one row in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm an Android newbie. I have a layout with three buttons on it per row. I want the text to show on the same row without wrapping to the next line and distorting the button size. What am I doing wrong? I have tried setting the button width to 0px so that the OS can automatically assign the width, but my components don't display onscreen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="addA"
    android:text="Add A" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button04"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button04"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button02"
    android:onClick="replaceBwithA"
    android:text="Replace B with A" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="removeA"
    android:text="Remove A" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="addB"
    android:text="Add B" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button05"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button02"
    android:onClick="removeB"
    android:text="Remove B" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Button05"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button01"
    android:onClick="replaceAwithB"
    android:text="Replace A with B" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button06"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button04"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Button03"
    android:onClick="attachA"
    android:text="Attach A" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button07"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button05"
    android:layout_below="@id/Button05"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Button06"
    android:onClick="detachA"
    android:text="Detach A" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button03"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use weight property in linear layout as given below.

```
<LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/headerbtns1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

```
        android:id="@+id/headerbtns"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"

            android:onClick="addA"
            android:text="Add A"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />
        <Button
             android:id="@+id/Button03"

            android:onClick="replaceBwithA"
            android:text="Replace B with A"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:onClick="removeA"
            android:text="Remove A"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

thus use LinearLayout within LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` or `vertical` orientation and arrange as per your requirement and you can `setWeight` according to make it more perfect view.